# Partial Deserialize of List<object>

Tags: c#, deserialization, binaryformatter

In my program I have serialization of List into file. This file became damaged.
When I try to deserialize this file into List I get Exception saying me that stream is not completed.

**Question**:

Can I deserialize part of List for example, just to restore some of data.
I use BinaryFormatter for serilization.

Comment: You probably need to monkeypatch the file to get it to a state where the binary serializer accepts it. What if you serialize another file, figure out where the original file broke off and tack on the end of the good file onto the bad file? Could that work? I'm pretty sure it's going to be a bit of work getting the file into a workable state.

Comment: Before all worked perfect. Just some error happened in program and I think serelization was aborted. Now everything work good, but data was lost. I have old(damaged) files and I ask if I can extract some data from it

Comment: And with *just* binary serialization, no, you can't, unfortunately. You will have to deal with the file, try to repair it, by modifying it enough for the program to accept it. It might not be possible, and it will probably involve a lot of work.

Comment: One thing you should take out of this, even if you cannot repair the file, is to perhaps change your serialization code. For instance, you might want to do this: 1. serialize to a new file under a new, temporary filename, in the same directory. 2. Rename the old file to a temporary backup filename, 3. Rename the new file to the correct filename, 4. Delete the original under the temporary filename. This way, if something crashes, you should still have the original file intact.

Comment: You will need to analyze where the file ends, serialize some data to a good file, and see if you can figure out what is missing. There is no automatic repair function or software for this, so it's going to be hard work, unfortunately.